# Error al seleccionar elemento de recycler view

Tags: android, recyclerview

No entiendo por que cuando selecciono algún elemento del recycler view, me marca también un elemento de la parte inferior.

Parte Superior:

[image: Esta es la parte superior]

Parte inferior:

[image: Esta es la parte inferior]

El codigo que tengo es el siguiente:

```
public class adapter_archivos extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

Context context;
List<Object> mitems;
public static List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

public adapter_archivos(Context context, List<Object> mitems) {
    this.context = context;
    this.mitems = mitems;
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.vista_list, parent, false);

    return new listaarchivos_holer(view);
}

public static class listaarchivos_holer extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView nombre;
    TextView peso;
    ImageView check;

    public listaarchivos_holer(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        nombre = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.nombre_archivo);
        peso = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.peso_archivo);
        check = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.check);
    }

}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    final listaarchivos_holer listaarchivos_holer = (listaarchivos_holer) holder;
    final contenedor_archivos contenedor_archivos = (contenedor_archivos) mitems.get(position);

    listaarchivos_holer.nombre.setText(contenedor_archivos.getNombre());
    listaarchivos_holer.peso.setText(contenedor_archivos.getPeso());
    listaarchivos_holer.check.setImageResource(contenedor_archivos.getCheck(contenedor_archivos.check));

    listaarchivos_holer.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            recibirPos(contenedor_archivos.getNombre(), listaarchivos_holer.check);

        }
    });

}

public void recibirPos(String nombre, ImageView nn) {

    String e = null;
    boolean agregar = true;

    for (int cont = 0; cont < list.size(); cont++) {

        e = list.get(cont);

        if (nombre.equalsIgnoreCase(e)) {
            agregar = false;
            list.remove(nombre);
            nn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            break;
        }
    }
    if (agregar) {
        list.add(nombre);
        nn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    Log.e("prueba", "" + list);

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mitems.size();
}
```

}

Lo que estoy tratando de hacer es que cuando se toque algún elemento del recycler, me guarde el nombre en una variable para después eliminar ese archivo (eso se como hacerlo), pero también trato de hacer que cuando lo toquen muestre una imagen de un check para saber que elemento han seleccionado, pero cuando selecciono el primero también se marca otro en la parte inferior del recycler, como puedo hacer para que solo marque o active la imagen en la opción que ha tocado ?

Answer (score 0):

Hola en el objeto contenedor_archivos puedes agregar una variables checked en el momento de hacer el bind de la vista preguntar

```
nn.setVisibility(contenedor_archivos.isChecked() ? View.VISIBLE : View.INVISIBLE);
```

no olvides darle el valor a checked cuando se necesario cambiarlo.

saludos

Comment: Al hacerlo de esta manera, donde agregaría el valor de nn ?

Comment: nn es el ImageView que tienes, el valor que tienes que guardar es el de si esta checked o no, dentro de contenedor_archivos